# ByteArray to Float in kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, type-conversion

I have a 4 bytes array which represent a float value. 
Since kotlin lack of bitwise operations for Byte how can I convert it to float in most optimal way?

Comment: Kotlin has shifts, or, and, xor, inversion operators https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html

Comment: You'll have to widen the Bytes to Ints for bit-operations, but that should honestly not be a real problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the Java NIO [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), it has the [`getFloat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getFloat()) and [`getFloat(index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getFloat(int)) functions for that:

```
val bytes = byteArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)

val buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)
val float1 = buffer.getFloat()  // Uses current position and increments it by 4
val float2 = buffer.getFloat(0) // Uses specified position
```

Comment: if your 4 bytes array represents a *Little Endian* float value you have to add `.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)`:
`val wrap = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)`

Comment: Three years later I am still looking for an answer. The problem with this solution is that it is just Java, and it will not work with Kotlin Multiplatform. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: if this doesn't work for you, have a look at `float.toBits()`, then use something like this: `new byte[] { (byte) (intBits >> 24), (byte) (intBits >> 16), (byte) (intBits >> 8), (byte) (intBits) }`

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this and here is how I use it, if I am not mistaken this should be Kotlin Native 1.3:

```kotlin
fun to4ByteArray(value: Int): ByteArray {
    return byteArrayOf(
        value.toByte(),
        (value shr 8).toByte(),
        (value shr 16).toByte(),
        (value shr 24).toByte(),
    )
}

fun to4ByteArray(value: Float): ByteArray {
    val bitRep = value.toRawBits()
    return byteArrayOf(
        bitRep.toByte(),
        (bitRep shr 8).toByte(),
        (bitRep shr 16).toByte(),
        (bitRep shr 24).toByte(),
    )
}

fun intFrom4ByteArray(value: ByteArray): Int {
    if(value.size != 4) return 0
    return  (value[3].toInt() and 0xff shl 24) or
            (value[2].toInt() and 0xff shl 16) or
            (value[1].toInt() and 0xff shl 8) or
            (value[0].toInt() and 0xff)

}

fun floatFrom4ByteArray(value: ByteArray): Float {
    if(value.size != 4) return 0.0f
    return Float.fromBits(
        (value[3].toInt() and 0xff shl 24) or
        (value[2].toInt() and 0xff shl 16) or
        (value[1].toInt() and 0xff shl 8) or
        (value[0].toInt() and 0xff)
    )
}
```